# Python PHP Integration

Tags: php, python

I am facing a problem here which I could not find a good solution for it. I am developing a mobile web app using php and I need a rule based inference engine (open source) - expert system. The only one I could find was Pyke in Python. So I need to integrate Pykes' source code with my php implementation. My service provider is not allowing any commands such as exec for security reasons. I tried PiP (Python to PHP module) but it has a lot of bugs.

Comment: Change your provider.

The Python via PECL method is probably the only option available. While a nice idea, it's a workaround however. And it's ridiculous that your provider lets you install a PHP module which allows for `py_eval("os.system()") calls`, but not use the native PHP eval() function.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Pyke; but when this type of situation arises for me, I usually end up wrapping the Python code with a web-service.  I then use PHP to make SOAP or cURL calls to the webservice.